# Is It possible to use WCF(C#) in that environment ? 

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

I have several "blackbox" that sends data to determinated IP and PORT, I can´t specify anything else (just IP and PORT)...

My server should be listening that PORT and catch information to send to MSMQ...

How can I set a WCF server to listening that PORT?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can control what's pushing data to the IP address/port, then yes, you could use WCF. Unfortunately, without some sort of contract/binding to specify the means by which your "server" and your "client" communicate, WCF won't help you much.

So if you can't control the client code, you'll need to "roll your own" listener. As @Rob Stevenson-Leggett suggested: [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx)

**Edit:**

> *Thanks Randolpho... So, I´ll develope
>   a Windows Service with the listener
>   and add the message to MSMQ. And in
>   the otner hand, I need a module to
>   read the queue (MSMQ) and add that to
>   DB... That module could be in WCF?
>   What you think?*

Yep. WCF provides the [MsmqIntegrationBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.msmqintegration.msmqintegrationbinding.aspx) for communicating on either end with an MSMQ.

Here's a nice tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789008.aspx

Comment: Thanks! 
I´m thinking in use a ThreadPool to process the clients... What you think?

Comment: Definitely. Pass processing of each opening on the port to a  threadpool. Be very careful, however -- you're opening yourself up to concurrency issues.

Comment: Thanks Randolpho...
So, I´ll develope a Windows Service with the listener and add the message to MSMQ.
And in the otner hand, I need a module to read the queue (MSMQ) and add that to DB... That module could be in WCF? What you think?

Comment: I think between us we've got a design here. Windows Service listening on the port and writing to it with a WCF service watching the MSMQ.

Comment: Just one last question...
What about if I dont use MSMQ ? Is it really necessary?
If I receive the data(tcp) and put directly on DB Instead of adding in MSMQ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would write a normal windows service that listens for the data.

Use the [TCPListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) or a similar class

Then plug on WCF as a seperate service that your windows service calls to write to the message queue, it's just a matter of configuration.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDaraWriterService
{
     [OperationContract]
     public void WriteDataToQueue(WriteDataToQueueMessage theDataEncapsulatedInAMessage)
     {
     }
}
```

Your windows service could probably write to the queue directly btw.

See here for more info on the message queue. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811053.aspx

Comment: Thanks... In that Windows service I need to set up a socket to listen that port, right?

Comment: Thanks...
What you think using ThreadPool to process the clients? Is it a good choice?